# a for loop with a list c#

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to apply a list to a for loop. `sumlist[sz]`  returns many numbers and the `if (sumOfVolumes4 >= sumlist[sz])` should be testing each one of them but only test the last number and not the others. `foundIndex` should return more than one answer but only returns one.

```
for (double d = 1.61D; d < 4.24; d+= 0.01D) {
    List<double> sumlist = new List<double>() {d};
                       
    for(int sz = 0; sz < sumlist.Count; sz++) {
        sumlist[sz] = (volumeValue /= sumlist[sz]);
                                    
        for(int barIndex = index; barIndex >= ChartBars.FromIndex; barIndex--) {
            sumOfVolumes4 +=  Bars.GetVolume(barIndex);
            if (sumOfVolumes4 >= sumlist[sz]) {
                foundIndex = barIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand Print(sumlist); and i get as many values as the difference between 1.61 and 4.24.

Comment: [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: You might need to explain it a bit better. I don't quite understand the objective behind this code. 
There must be a different way to proceed than 3 for loops. 
Maybe some Linq or Foreach?

Comment: Also, sumlist always contains 1 value since you assign it at the start of the loop.
So the second loop iterates only once.

An idea would be eventually to do a first forLoop to add all the values to sumList. 
Then foreach on sumlist

Comment: First for loop enumerate 1.61 to 4.24, the second one apply a list to divide 5000 by  1.61, 1.62 etc till 4.24 In the third for loop i am having 5000/1.61 = 3105, 5000/1.62, 3086, etc. and each answer is tested to find with the if statement the barIndex equal to 3105, 3086 etc. foundIndex should enumerate all barIndex meeting the condition.

Answer (score 1):

From the code provided it seems there is no need for the second for loop as `sumlist` is always getting created newly and contains only one entry which is assigned when it is created. Actually there is no need for the list `sumlist` itself

So your provided code boils down to :

```
  for (double d = 1.61D; d < 4.24; d+= 0.01D) 
  {
     double sumList = (volumeValue /= d);
     for(int barIndex = index; barIndex >= ChartBars.FromIndex; barIndex--) 
     {
        sumOfVolumes4 +=  Bars.GetVolume(barIndex);
        if (sumOfVolumes4 >= sumList) 
        {
           foundIndex = barIndex;
           break;
        }
     }
  }
```

Also your `foundIndex` variable is being updated every time you increment you outermost for loop index. It's better to save a list of fixed indices to store the `foundIndex` result.

```
      List<int> foundIndices = new List<int>();
      for (double d = 1.61D; d < 4.24; d+= 0.01D) 
      {
         double sumList = (volumeValue /= d);
         for(int barIndex = index; barIndex >= ChartBars.FromIndex; barIndex--) 
         {
            sumOfVolumes4 +=  Bars.GetVolume(barIndex);
            if (sumOfVolumes4 >= sumList) 
            {
               //foundIndex = barIndex;
               foundIndices.Add(barIndex);
               break;
            }
         }
      }

       foreach(var foundIndex in foundIndices)
       {
          Print(foundIndex);
       }
```

Comment: By eliminating volumeValue you are comparing 1.61 , 1.62, 1.63 to 4.24 with  sumOfVolumes4  which is a larger number.  sumOfVolumes4  return volume for each bar which is bigger than 1.61.  sumOfVolumes4 = volume and must be compare to sumlist[sz] who also return a list of volume.

Comment: @FrankDuc Thanks for tthe comment. I missed it completely when removing the second loop. I have edited my answer

Comment: If i Print(barIndex); its returning the same number over and over. If i Print(foundIndices); outside i get sumlistSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] inside the brackets it return nothing, One part is working double sumList = (volumeValue /= d); return the right answer but compare to sumOfVolumes4 it fail the test. Keep in mind sumOfVolumes4 cumulate the volume in each barIndex 500, 1000, 1500 etc and when it meat one of the value in sumList it should return barIndex of cumulative volume and than reach for the next one.

Comment: @FrankDuc You need to print each found index value individually using a loop. I have edited my answer for your reference

Comment: Like i said it still return many times bar 1227 which is the beginning of the for loop (index) it goes from bar 1227 (index) till there is no bar to for loop. Its the equivalent of Print(barIndex); after the second for loop. thanks for trying hard.